# Unexpected token '<' when using grunt to compile .js script files to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, deployment, gruntjs

I'm currently using **grunt** to inject application script files into index.html, and I've configured it as follows:

```
scripts: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<script type="text/javascript" src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
              ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
               '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/template/js/*.js',
               '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/scripts/components/sidebar/*.js',
               '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/scripts/components/modal/modalEffects.js',
               '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/scripts/components/input/inputFiller.js',
               '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/scripts/socket.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/scripts/app.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js']
            ]
        }
      },
```

Which generates the following HTML:

```
<!-- injector:js -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/jquery.1.11.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/landio.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/main.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/components/sidebar/classie.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/components/sidebar/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/components/sidebar/sidebarEffects.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/components/modal/modalEffects.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/components/input/inputFiller.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/socket.js"></script>
 <!-- endinjector -->
```

The app ends up working perfectly on localhost. However, when deployed on AWS, I see the following in my console:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: If the code is working ok on localhost and presumably you aren't getting these errors then I would look at what AWS is doing to your files. Has AWS injected some code? Also, what is the difference with the files in the sidebar, model and input folders as they do not produce any errors?